# Accessing menu items from view controller in a storyboard, OS X, swift

Tags: macos, swift, xcode-storyboard

I am building an OS X app in Xcode using storyboards.  I have found that working with menu items is difficult and non-intuitive.  The menu items are in a different scene (the application) than the view controller, and can not be connected to the view controller by the usual control-drag methods to create an outlet/action.  I need to access menu items from the main view controller.  I have figured out how to connect actions via first responder chain.  However, I also would like to enable/disable menu items from the view controller, and I see no way to create an outlet to be able to do this.

I am new to OS X programming.  I feel like I am missing something very basic here.  I have watched several WWDC videos related to storyboards, and have not seen a good example showing the proper way to work with menus.  Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to work with menus. The traditional Cocoa way is to add an action method to First Responder proxy in IB.

Then flesh out the same action method in the NSResponder subclass that you want. Declare it in the header too.

This will then receive the action message via the Responder Chain.

Read up on the Responder Chain.

Comment: I did hook up the action in the first responder chain. But I believe I need to hook up an outlet to be able to set the menu item properties, such as enabled/disabled from my view controller.

Comment: This is also normally done indirectly with NSUserIntefaceValidations https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UIValidation/UIValidation.html

Comment: It means you implement a method in a responder that validates an interface item. If your responder is not there, it acts like invalid.

Comment: That works!  Thanks much.  I found the menu programming guide in the link, that explains it all.